# Are Ginkgo trees in Japan rare and if so, where can I find them?

Tags: japan, sightseeing, nature-and-wildlife

I was wondering where is the best place in Japan to see the Ginkgo Biloba trees. My friend says there are many in and around Tokyo.

Are there many trees of this kind in other areas (e.g. Kyoto etc)? Or would they appear only in specific places...

It would be a shame to go to Japan and not see these beautiful trees!!

Comment: Japan is big and 'best' is rather unspecific, do you mean most accessible ? biggest ? most popular ?

Comment: It could just be one big/historic tree or numerous trees (so either/both). And yes, accessible.

Comment: There's a very nice one in the botanical garden in Cologne. Not very old obviously, only a few hundred years.

Comment: Also females are nice because you can get the nuts. I have 2 male two female where I live in UK.

Comment: Incidentally - since I see you are from New York - there are a lot of ginkgo trees in Central Park. The Conservatory has marked theirs, but about 3% of street trees all over NYC are ginkgo.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

While what constitutes a "best" spot is subjective, here are some popular options:

[**Icho Namiki**](http://www.japan-talk.com/jt/new/icho-namiki-avenue)

This road is located in Tokyo, between the Gaienmae and Aoyama-Itchome stations. The best time to visit is from mid-november to early december.

[image]

---

[**Rikugien garden**](http://www.japan-guide.com/e/e3026.html)

While this doesnt feature only Ginkgo trees, you can enjoy the view in this traditional japanese garden.

[image]

---

[**Nishi Honganji**](http://www.japan-guide.com/e/e3920.html)

The temple grounds feature many Ginkgo trees, plus you get so visit one of the biggest temples around.

[image]

---

The lesson here is that there aren't many dedicated spots for Ginkgo trees, but they are more or less omnipresent in Japan.

Visit during the end of november and you are sure to get your fill of beautiful colors.

[Here is a resource page for other spots in Tokyo.](http://www.japan-guide.com/e/e3061.html)

[And here is the same page for Kyoto.](http://www.japan-guide.com/e/e3953.html)

Comment: OK thanks, so more or less every city will have nice Ginkgo trees dotted around, is my impression of what you are saying.

Comment: Yes, try to focus on parks and gardens as they are most likely to have them.

Comment: Oh god, the Icho Namiki road must be horrible during the fall.

Comment: Any sources for your pictures? I feel like some of those could be awesome if they were originally a higher resolution.

Comment: @kevin google image search... I never went in Japan during fall so I dont have any of my own, sadly.

Answer (score 14):

Visit Toyko's [Shinjuku Gyoen National Garden](http://www.env.go.jp/garden/shinjukugyoen/english/index.html) to experience the ginko tunnel in the Meiji-Jingu Gaien, the golden canopy and carpet the most glorious in the autumn.

[image]

Comment: Note the cost is 300 yen for entry.

Answer (score 9):

You could visit the biggest Ginkgo biloba tree in Japan. It is the **[Kitakanegasawa no Ichou](http://www.monumentaltrees.com/en/jpn/tohoku/aomori/3146_kitakanegasawa/)**.

It has a girth of about 22m, and is estimated to be over 1000 years old. In terms of girth, it is probably the second biggest tree in Japan (after the [Kamoh no Ohkusu](http://www.monumentaltrees.com/en/jpn/kyushu/kagoshima/11753_buildings/) Camphor tree).

[image: Kitakanegasawa no Ichou]
*Photo By Aomorikuma, licensed as CC-BY-SA-3.0, via [Wikimedia Commons](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File%3AGinkgo_Kitakanegasawa_Japan.jpg)*

It is near [Kitakanegasawa Station](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kitakanegasawa_Station), in Aomori Prefecture, at the northern end of Honshu.

Answer (score 8):

There are Ginkgo trees in a lot of areas of Japan. So it depends a lot on where you want to go otherwise. Since the other answers focus on Tokyo I will just throw some answers for the Kansai area.

Osaka:

There are many Ginkgo trees lining Midosuji which is the central street going from Namba to Umeda which is a nice stroll.

[image: Autumn on Midosuju street]

There are also Ginkgo trees as well as many other tree's such as maple in the Osaka castle garden which makes for a nice view.

Kyoto:
There are many places in the central town and around temples. Such as kiyomizu-dera.

My favorite place in Kyoto for Autumn colors is Arashiyama. You can also take the [Torokko](http://www.japan-guide.com/e/e3965.html) which is a train that goes through the valley where you can see a lot of foliage. Then you can also take a boat ride on the river to get back to Arashiyama

Nara:

Nara park contains a lot of Ginkgo trees as well.

Answer (score 6):

There is also a famous gingko tree in Tokyo in the University of Tokyo (accessible to public).

[image]

Comment: Why is it famous ?

Comment: The gingko is the symbol of the University of Tokyo, and the trees lining the avenue are over 100 years old: http://www.u-tokyo.ac.jp/en/whyutokyo/hongo_hi_002.html